# How to delete categories in WordPress

Tags: categories

I'm trying to delete a category in WordPress but i can't find out how. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To delete a category from WP , first you need to open the category listing.
It will come when you will mouse over the Posts.

[image]

Once you click on Categories, it will display all the categories.

Then mouse over to the  category which you want to delete and it will show you an Delete link.

[image]

You just need to click on Delete and choose "OK" from the Alert box.

Thanks